# How to revert back to older version in google play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I released a new update in the android app which is getting crashed. I want to revert back to previous version of the app. Because google play console is saying update will be released in 2-7 days which is very long. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't rollback a version once released. But you can revert the changes on your code and upload a new APK with a higher version code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but you can not "revert" updates in the Google-Play-Store. You need to set a new `versionCode`, `versionName` in your app and create a new release in the console